# How to make SQLite database on Android get data from a database server?

Tags: android, database, oracle, sqlite

I have an android application with a SQLite database, and it works good.
but now i need to make the SQLite database on android to get all its data from a database server
so when i change anything on the database server, it will be changed in SQLite.

I have read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12095_01/nav/portal_booklist.htm) documentation from oracle, which talks about SQLite mobile client
and sync between it and SQLite database ..

So, is this a good way to perform this goal or there is another way to make it true ?
and if there is any other suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

You can implement web services both on your server and your app.In first launch request data from server and write to your sqlite database.